# Create a Preview Pane Control in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I need to create a React Component similar to a preview pane.  These are search result so what I need the component to do is when the user clicks the "Preview" link or button a smaller panel opens up to show a preview.  I have the URL text that I need to send to the control to generate the preview (these are search results from a SharePoint REST api call).

What I need to know since I am new to react, is what kind of component do I need to create.  I am working in Visual Studio 2017 and have had success creating generic React components using this code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

directive, so I am familiar with creating the Components, I just don't know which components to use.  Can someone help with with the types of component I should use to build a simple preview?  I am not necessarily looking for code, just a list of components to use or a link to tutorial

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the control using an IFrame to host the "preview" url. The problem was with the URL that was being passed in.